# getElementById(element).innerHtml returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the innerHtml of an element in the page, but the innerHtml always returns undefined. I have already tested the getElementById and it's okay, the method can actually find the form element from which i want to get the html.

The javascript function will be called by a button, and it will open a new window with the form content:

```
function Popup(data){           
   var formElement = document.getElementById(data);
   var content = formElement.innerHtml;
   var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
   mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Checklist</title>');
   mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
   mywindow.document.write(content);
   mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
   mywindow.print();
   mywindow.close();
   return true;
}
```

I've checked the formElement variable value and it's : [object HTMLFormElement].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The property is `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`. JavaScript property names are case-sensitive.

Comment: What a silly mistake, thank you very much, i'm new to Javascript and didn't notice that before.